# R: ordering rows in reshape2

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I have a situation where I need to *melt* the data using the **reshape2** package in R.

```
melt(head(faithful), measure.vars = names(faithful))
```

this gives the output:

```
    variable  value
1  eruptions  3.600
2  eruptions  1.800
...
7    waiting 79.000
8    waiting 54.000
...
```

I would like to order the output to have the first few rows according to the columns in dataframe. For example:

```
    variable  value
1  eruptions  3.600
2    waiting 79.000
3  eruptions  1.800
4    waiting 54.000
...
```

How can I achieve this by avoiding loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an extra column `tag`

```
df<-faithful
df<-cbind(df,tag=1:nrow(faithful))
df2<-melt(df,id.vars = "tag")
df2<-df2[order(df2$tag),]
df2$tag<-NULL#drop it like it's hot
head(df2)
```

Ergo:

```
     variable  value
1   eruptions  3.600
273   waiting 79.000
2   eruptions  1.800
274   waiting 54.000
3   eruptions  3.333
275   waiting 74.000
```

Comment: I'd say OP should keep the tag. If they care about sorting so much, they ought to at least retain some means of doing it, eh.

Comment: tried to imitate the output of OP :) That's the reason of the 'drop'.

Answer (score 2):

I know a `reshape2` solution was requested but another good way would be to use the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
head(faithful) %>% mutate(tag = 1:n()) %>% gather(var, val, -tag) %>% arrange(tag)

   tag       var    val
1    1 eruptions  3.600
2    1   waiting 79.000
3    2 eruptions  1.800
4    2   waiting 54.000
# etc
```

No intermediate objects needed.